# Why do I get notifications for chat pings from rooms I'm currently in?

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

I'm sorry I have no screenshot for this, much less hand-drawn red circles, but it's a bit annoying nonetheless.

It often happens that I'm in a chatroom, someone says something to me (pinging me), I reply, everything goes well. I open up a stack in another tab and I see a notification. I click on it, and lo and behold! it's the chat ping I responded to.

Why am I

1. Notified for a ping in a room I'm in *at that moment*?
2. ...Especially when the ping has been cleared (by responding)?

---

This may be the same question as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199786/239016, but it seems different to me.

Comment: You sure the ping notification is cleared i.e. the number in red circle in chat is removed? Sometimes it's not being removed by itself when writing a message and we have to click it to manually "clear" it.

Comment: Yes, the number in the red circle went down or disappeared.

Comment: Well, being in the room does not prevent the notification from arriving, one can stay for weeks in the room, idle. However if the ping was cleared... can't repro this.

Comment: Wait... one thing I can think of is super ping i.e. ping by moderator, who explicitly writes your user id: those always arrive to the inbox. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope, not a mod super ping.

Comment: I'll try and see if I pinpoint a specific incidence.

Comment: I've had this happen to me recently, too. Not sure what's going on there.